# How to know whether user is adding or removing character in Input

Tags: javascript, input, sapui5, onchange

I am using `sap.m.Input` control and I attached `liveChange` event for control. I have a use case where I want to know whether user is adding or removing characters in `Input`. I have tried following thing in my controller:

```
onLiveChangeInput: function (oEvent) {
    var oInput = oEvent.getSource();
    if (oEvent.getParameter("newValue").length > oInput._lastValue.length) {
        console.log("added");
    } else {
        console.log("deleted");
    }
}
```

This works well for adding characters in Input but it fails for deleting characters because `oInput._lastValue` is not getting updated for `liveChange`. is there any better way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: store your own _lastValue in your `this` object (initially empty string), update it at the end of your event handler, use it to compare to (instead of oInput._lastValue)

Comment: Thanks @Marc that helped!! but is there any way we can get previous value of input before liveChange?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how the input is filled initially

Comment: check if the user is using the "backspace or delete" key using keyboard events. And write the logic accordingly.

Comment: @santhosh what if he is navigating with arrows?